# iOS cannot load custom objects from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsarray

I have a custom object, Person, that has a couple simple properties. These are name, username, email.

I am pulling from a web service the JSON data which is basically an NSArray of users.

I then pass this to a custom method:

```
[self gatherPeopleFromArray:feedData];
```

Here is that function:

```
- (void) gatherTweetsFromArray:(NSArray *)data {

    if (data != nil) {

        NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:data.count];

        for (int i = 0; i < data.count; i++) {

            NSString *name = [[data objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"name"]
            NSString *username = [[data objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"username"]
            NSString *email = [[data objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"email"]

            Person *aPerson = [Person alloc] init];

            aPerson.name = name;
            aPerson.username = username;
            aPerson.email = email;

            [temp insertObject:aPerson atIndex:i];

        }

        self.users = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:temp];

        // This is a test function example
        NSLog(@"%@", [self.users objectAtIndex:10]);            

    }
```

This works perfectly, and everything will display in the console as expected, so the array is populating with the custom Person objects.

When I try to access this in cellForRowAtIndexPath, it comes up as null as if the objects don't exist properly.

I am sure this has to do with converting NSArray to NSMutableArrays and such, but not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Any help would be great, thanks!

EDIT:

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *identifier = @"user_cell";

    UserCell *cell = [self.usersTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UserCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }


    if (self.users != nil) {

        Person *thePerson = [self.users objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        NSLog(@"%@", thePerson.username);

        // Perform Cell Setup Here

    }


    return cell;

}
```

This is the start of a project so I am not concerned yet about setting up the cells, just the data model.

Comment: How does this possibly work?  You're calling `gatherPeopleFromArray:` but the method is called `gatherTweetsFromArray:`?

Comment: What does your code in cellForRowAtIndexPath look like?

Comment: Is `self.users` an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`?  If it's an `NSArray`, you need to fix the line... should be: `self.users = [NSArray arrayWithArray:temp];`

Comment: What is self.users properties? Is it a strong reference or a weak reference? Search your code for all references to self.users and make sure it is not set to null elsewhere. If you are not setting it to null, then it means the OS is, which means it is a weak reference.

Comment: Or the table is only reloaded before the array is prepared...

Comment: Dollars to donuts you're accessing a different instance of the array.

Comment: The gatherTweetsFromArray is the name from another project that uses the same method but for tweets. I must have copied the other projects method, but it is identical except for the name. self.users is a NSMutableArray.

Comment: self.users is also not weak, it is strong, and I checked all other aspects of the code and it is not set to null anywhere.

Comment: How about showing us the `cellForRowAtIndex`?

Comment: Is it going inside if (self.users != nil) ?

Comment: Have you tried calling reloadData at the end of gatherTweetsFromArray:. Since the download from the web is asynchronous, the table view all have called its data source methods before self.users is populated.